# Assembly 8086 - Issues with parameters on stack

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I've some doubts on stack and access0 to its values. I wrote a program which required a numeric code of 3 values (precisely 3 3 2) and I want to check first if the number of values is correct (3 in this case) and second if every single value correspond respectively with 3, 3 and 2.
Here's my code:

```
.section .data
   error:
      .ascii "Error!\n"
   error_len:
       .long . - error
.section .text
   .global _start
_start:
   popl %eax         #first element on stack: number of parameters
                     #program name + three values
   cmp $4, %eax
   jne err
   pop %eax          #second element: program's name (useless)
   pop %eax          #third element: first value of the code
   cmp $51, %eax     #compare with ASCII code of "3"
   jne err
   pop %eax          #fourth element: first value of the code
   cmp $51, %eax     #compare with ASCII code of "3"
   jne err
   pop %eax          #fifth element: first value of the code
   cmp $50, %eax     #compare with ASCII code of "2"
   jne err
   jmp exit

err:    
   movl $4, %eax     #print error message with sys write
   movl $1, %ebx
   leal error, %ecx
   movl error_len, %edx
   int $0x80
   jmp exit

exit:
   movl $1, %eax     #exit
   xorl %ebx, %ebx
   int $0x8
```

When I launch the program (./run 3 3 2) the first check is correct (number of parameters) but when I check the first value instruction cmp failed because there is a different value from 51 (sometimes 0, sometimes 47, etc) so I'm not sure how stack works! Any help? Thanks!
PS: I work with Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and I use gdb for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing characters and string pointers (addresses). What you want is:

```
cmpb $51, (%eax)  # compare the first byte pointed to by %eax with the value 51
```

..and so on for the other arguments.

Note that it's perfectly fine to write `$'3'` instead of `$51`, so there's really no need to use ASCII codes directly here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I tried your code but the error persist :/

Comment: It works just fine for me with my suggested changes. Except that you've written `int $0x8` instead of `int $0x80` right at the end, which causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: You're right! I launched the wrong program! xD thank you again!